# Is black spotting on the lungs a common benign variance, or a sign of pathology?

Tags: lungs, organ-transplant, ischaemia, pneumothorax

I recently found [this article](https://interestingengineering.com/attaching-damaged-lungs-to-pigs-can-heal-them-experiment-shows) which shows an externally-healed lung donation before transplant. The left image is supposedly the lung pre-treatment, and right is post.

In both of these images, black spots can be seen over the lung. However, in the article, they mention that the lung was nearly fully recovered. I have seen other images like this in journals and other media reports -- notably, [this viral report](https://metro.co.uk/2019/08/07/student-18-says-vape-juul-pods-almost-killed-lung-collapsed-10530939/) that covered a young man's pneumothorax story, but I have never read an explanation as to what black spotting signifies.

Are black spots like this a normal / common benign variance among individuals (similar to freckles on the skin)? Or does it usually signify some type of pathology (ischemia or hemorrhage or anthracosis/tar)?

Comment: Related https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/is-smokers-lungs-a-lie

Comment: Yes, I did see and read through that thread. However, the question is still at large.